# Python process not recognized with service file

Tags: python, ubuntu, service

I have a process [goodreads-user-scraper](https://github.com/YashTotale/goodreads-user-scraper) that runs fine within a cron scheduler script that I run from my Ubuntu terminal.

From my Ubuntu server terminal, I navigate to the directory containing scheduler.py and write:

```bash
python scheduler.py
```

This runs fine. It scrapes the site and saves files to the output_dir I have assigned inside the script.

Now, I want to run this function using a service file (socialAggregator.service).

When I set up a service file in my Ubuntu server to run scheduler.py, goodreads-user-scraper is not recognized. It's the exact same file I just ran from the terminal.

Why is goodreads-user-scraper not found when the service file calls the script?

Any ideas?

Error message form syslog file

```
Jan 12 22:13:15 speedypersonal2 python[2668]: --user_id: 1: goodreads-user-scraper: not found
```

socialAggregator.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Run Social Aggregator scheduler - collect data from API's and store in socialAggregator Db --- DEVELOPMENT ---
After=network.target

[Service]
User=nick
ExecStart= /home/nick/environments/social_agg/bin/python /home/nick/applications/socialAggregator/scheduler.py --serve-in-foreground

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

scheduler.py

```py
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import json
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import os
from sa_config import ConfigLocal, ConfigDev, ConfigProd
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import subprocess



if os.environ.get('CONFIG_TYPE')=='local':
    config = ConfigLocal()
elif os.environ.get('CONFIG_TYPE')=='dev':
    config = ConfigDev()
elif os.environ.get('CONFIG_TYPE')=='prod':
    config = ConfigProd()


#Setting up Logger
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(name)s:%(message)s')
formatter_terminal = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(filename)s:%(name)s:%(message)s')

#initialize a logger
logger_init = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger_init.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

#where do we store logging information
file_handler = RotatingFileHandler(os.path.join(config.PROJ_ROOT_PATH,'social_agg_schduler.log'), mode='a', maxBytes=5*1024*1024,backupCount=2)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

#where the stream_handler will print
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter_terminal)

logger_init.addHandler(file_handler)
logger_init.addHandler(stream_handler)



def scheduler_funct():
    logger_init.info(f"- Started Scheduler on {datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')}-")
 
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

    job_collect_socials = scheduler.add_job(run_goodreads,'cron', hour='*', minute='13', second='15')#Testing


    scheduler.start()


    while True:
        pass


def run_goodreads():
    logger_init.info(f"- START run_goodreads() -")
    output_dir = os.path.join(config.PROJ_DB_PATH) 
    goodreads_process = subprocess.Popen(['goodreads-user-scraper', '--user_id', config.GOODREADS_ID,'--output_dir', output_dir], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    logger_init.info(f"- send subprocess now on::: goodreads_process.communicate()  -")
    _, _ = goodreads_process.communicate()

    logger_init.info(f"- FINISH run_goodreads() -")

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    scheduler_funct()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the environment which the service file was using was not the same as the environment used when I run the script in the terminal.

Below is the service file that now works.

```
[Unit]
Description=Run Social Aggregator scheduler - collect data from API's and store in socialAggregator Db --- DEVELOPMENT ---
After=network.target

[Service]
User=nick
ExecStart= /home/nick/environments/social_agg/bin/python /home/nick/applications/socialAggregator/scheduler.py --serve-in-foreground
Environment=PATH=/home/nick/environments/social_agg/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I added `Environment=PATH=<path_from_terminal_and_venv_activated>`

For additional clarity, path_from_terminal_and_venv_activated is obtained by:

1. Activiating my python venv in the terminal
2. copying the result of echo $PATH